# How should be the format for literature references that are websites (URLs)?

Tags: technical-writing, websites

In technical writings are good established standards for formatting literature references. But that doesn't work this well for URLs. How should these references be formatted?

Comment: Every style guide I've seen has shown the proper way to format websites in a Works Cited page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the question [What are the most common style manuals?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-are-the-most-common-style-manuals), find the one that is pertinent to the intended publisher of your piece of technical writing, and look up how they suggest you format a URL.  Make sure you have a recent edition, but all style manuals I know of should offer you their canonical way to handle URLs.