# Adding related work to an academic project report

Tags: word-choice, academic-writing

In an academic project report, what phrasing should I use to introduce and explain related work? I have to explain several previous projects; I would like to be clear but also avoid repetition.

I came up with the following two examples:

> Previous research in this area has focused on the following: ...
>
> In this section we discuss related work...

Comment: What question are you asking? I'm not getting this. (Also, you may want to define "best".)

Comment: I believe that he's asking the best way to segue between his words and when he's about to start talking about someone else's words that were seen in another academic paper.

Comment: I think I understand the question; I've edited appropriately. Noah, hope this is good :)

Comment: @standback - that makes more sense.

Comment: @noah - Are you using APA or MLA? Or another style guide altogether?

Comment: @Standback- Thanks. Yep, makes more sense now.

Comment: @NeilFein- Well, I am not really sure. It has an Abstract, Introduction, Related Work, Implementation, Experiments, Conclusion and Future Work. I think I would put it under APA.

Comment: Your school/department/journal should have the style guide specified somewhere. If it's too early to tell (i.e., you're working on a paper and don't know where it's going to be published), you can make some good guesses with the information in [this question](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/72/26).

Comment: @NeilFein- Alright. It's APA. Thanks for pointing that out, though.

Answer (score 1):

"Previous research in this area has focused on..." sounds perfectly fine as an intro to a "related research" section. You may want to make it clear whether it's *your* previous work or other research in the area that you're building on.